# The MLP output of a neural network can be written as $\|x\|\|w_l\|\cos(\theta_l)$: why is the norm easier to maximize?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, papers, deep-neural-networks

The MLP output of a neural network is a dot product between the weights and the input and therefore can be written as $\|x\|\|w_l\|\cos(\theta_l)$ (see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Geometric_definition) for more details), where $x$ is the input, $w_l$ is the weights of layer $l$ and $\theta_l$ is the angle between them.

I read this in a paper: [Angular Visual Hardness](https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.02279). The paper stated that it's much easier to maximize the norms $\|x\|$ and $\|w_l\|$ than the cosine similarity. Why is this the case? Just because $\cos(\theta_l)$ gives less weight because it's bounded between $[-1,1]$? Or is it due to the gradient? So, why is the norm easier to maximize?